# Prevent bash-completion adding an extra space when the word is incomplete

Tags: shell, completion, bash-completion

When using Emacs shell with the auto-completion feature enabled, I notice that whenever I perform typing and auto-completing a command, Emacs shell always adds an extra space after the first word. I illustrate this issue by an example as follow:

- Suppose that my current working directory is `user@linux ~/foo/bar $`
- Now if I want to type the command `mkdir` by auto-completion, I first type `mk`, and then press `TAB` to show a list of completion possibilities and press `ENTER` choose `mkdir`. Now, a whitespace is added at the end of `mkdir`, which is indicated by the pair `[ ]`

  `user@linux ~/foo/bar $ mkdir[ ]`

  In this scenario, adding a whitespace after the command `mkdir` is fine since `mkdir` is a full command, I certainly want to type a new word after that.
- But if the first word is not a full command, but a part of a command, a white-space is still added and it is quite inconvenient.

  For example, I want to type and auto-complete the command such as `~/workspace/tool/my-command`

  Then, if I type `~/work` first and then press `TAB` to auto-complete, Emacs shell will automatically add a new white-space after the first directory `~/workspace`, which is indicated by `[ ]`

  `user@linux ~/foo/bar $ ~/workspace[ ]`

  This is an unwanted white-space, since I have to delete it, in order to continue typing the rest of `~/workspace/tool/my-command`

Is there anybody know how to make Emacs shell knows when an extra white-space should be added?

FYI, I am using the Spacemacs distribution of Emacs.

I discovered that this is due to the package bash-completion of Emacs. After removing it, the Emacs shell works as usual.

Comment: It shouldn't do that, and I can't reproduce this on Emacs 26.0.50. But I use shell-mode a lot and for years, and this is not normal behaviour - the space should not be added. Try to reproduce the problem starting from `emacs -Q`. If that fixes the issue, as it should, then there's something in your config that has caused the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler for the suggestion. Yes, you are right! This issue doesn't happen with `emacs -Q`. I also use Emacs 26.0.50. I will look into my configuration.

Comment: I discovered that this is due to the package `bash-completion` of Emacs. After removing it, the Emacs shell works as usual

Answer (score 0):

The `bash-completion` package addresses that issue with this setting:

```
(setq bash-completion-nospace t)
```

I find that is not perfect but it's a better compromise.

There doesn't seem to be a thorough treatment of the issue anywhere but there is a little discussion of it on github: https://github.com/szermatt/emacs-bash-completion/search?q=nospace&type=Issues